# Query bytea field in postgres via command line

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a bytea field, and it would be convenient if I could do queries via the command line (or pgAdmin's query executor). I've got the hex value as a string. Is there a built in function to convert hex to bytea?

I'd like to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE my_bytea_field=some_???_function('fa26e312');
```

where 'fa26e312' is the hex value of the bytea field I want.

Note: this is just to be helpful while I'm developing / debugging things, I can do it via code but I'd like to be able to do it by hand in a query.

Comment: The new (9.0+) ["hex" format"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html#AEN5037) is not working for you?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using built-in [`decode(string text, type text)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-binarystring.html) function (it returns `bytea`). You can run queries via CLI using [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-psql.html) in non-interactive mode, that is with `-c` switch (there are some formatting options if you like):

```
psql -c "SELECT * FROM table WHERE my_bytea_field=decode('fa26e312', 'hex');"
```

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE test(id serial, my_bytea_field bytea);
INSERT INTO test (my_bytea_field) VALUES
    (E'\\320\\170'::bytea),
    (E'\\100\\070'::bytea),
    (E'\\377\\377'::bytea);

psql -tc "SELECT * FROM test WHERE my_bytea_field=decode('ffff', 'hex');"
  3 | \377\377
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE my_bytea_field=E'\\xfa26e312';
```

Just as in the example in the [Binary Data Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html) docs (note the E'\\x' prefix):

```
SELECT E'\\xDEADBEEF';
```

Answer (score 0):

under psql console, you can see its bytea content by default, such as:

[image]

also you can query like this (such as in pg_admin) :

```
xxx=# select id, encode(code_hash, 'hex') from your_table where id = 1195;

  id  |                              encode
------+------------------------------------------------------------------
 1195 | c5e5dcf215925f7ef4dfaf5f4b4f105bc321c02776d6e7d52a1db3fcd9d011a4
```